# How to get clickstream log from Android Debug Bridge (ADB)

Tags: android, logging, adb

Good day all,

So currently I am trying to test some UAT features,
In order to do so, I want to check what was the user path in an Android application,
To be more specific, what the user clicked on to achieve a certain goal.

I tried to read ADB logs but unfortunately didn't get anything :(
Any idea how to do so :)?

Thanks All!

Comment: could you please be more specific? which information you want to get when the user clicks on something? Feel free to add some examples

Comment: You would need to find some library to add to your app to generate this data.

Comment: @Lino Hi, thanks for your replay. Specifically I want to know what buttons did the user click in order to perform a certain function in order to measure the wrong clicks and hence analyze his performance. for instance, I want the user to perform in Calculator app "1+1 =" So I want to know if he for example clicked on "1" then "-" instead of "+" then changed it to "+"... I am using ADB Shell but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, Thanks for your replay. I am using ADB shell inside a windows forums application where I launch Android emulator and view ADB logs. Any idea what kind of library I shall use?